# Compilation error :missing return statement

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a method that takes a string value as a parameter and then checks if that string value exists in the database! The method should return true if the string value already exist and false otherwise! Before i run the method  i get a compilation error " missing return statement"! Does anyone spot an error in the code below ?

```
 public boolean checkID(String sid)
 {
    try 
    {
        String sessionID = null;
        if(dBConnection.connect())
        {
            Connection con = dBConnection.getConnection();
            String query = "SELECT sidvalue FROM sessionid where tokenvalue='" + sid + "'";
            Statement pstmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = pstmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (resultset.next())
            {
                sessionID = resultset.getString(1);
                if(sid.equalsIgnoreCase(sessionID))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            dBConnection.disconnect();     
        }//End of If statement

    }//End of Try block
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
 }//End of method
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if the execution doesn't pass to the if statement and/or while loop? There is no return value for such cases. Use a boolean variable or `false` value to return. Just add a `return false;` statement after this line `dBConnection.disconnect();`, i.e. after the while loop inside the if statement of your **try block**, it will be done.

By the way, I suggest you to use database disconnection statement in a `finally` clause, not inside try block. It's probable that `dBConnection.disconnect();` will not be executed if your method returns any value inside the while loop. Move this line `dBConnection.disconnect();`    to a finally block just after the catch block like this:

```
try
{
...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
...
}
finally
{
   dBConnection.disconnect();   
}
```

Comment: What do mean a default boolean ? Thanks

Comment: I still get the same error when adding a **return false** after the while loop!

Comment: @Xris check my answer carefully please.

Comment: I moved **dB.disconnect()** and **return false**; statements to a finally block and there is no error anymore! I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

If the if statement, if(dBConnection.connect()), returns false then there is no return statement for the method. You can either add a finally statement or you can just attach an else to the if returning the value you want

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It should resolve your issue:

```
public boolean checkID(String sid) {
    try {
        String sessionID = null;
        if(dBConnection.connect()) {
            Connection con = dBConnection.getConnection();
            String query = "SELECT sidvalue FROM sessionid where tokenvalue='" + sid + "'";
            Statement pstmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = pstmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultset.next()) {
                sessionID = resultset.getString(1);
                if(sid.equalsIgnoreCase(sessionID)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }        
        } else {
             return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }

    finally {
        dBConnection.disconnect();     
    }
}//End of method
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if it did.  Does this compile?

Comment: Compilation has been completed successfully!